# What can I do if my Australian visitor visa application has not been decided yet? - November 19th,2018

Tags: visas, australia

I live in Cameroon, married and 32 years old. I need to complete a short course for 3 months and my University said I was not eligible to get a confirmation of enrolment because the course is only 3 month. They adviced that I apply for a visitor visa. School starts on January 17th.

I lodged my application online. I received a confirmation of application received after paying the required fees via IMMI account.

It is passed standard established processing times since I applied for my visitor visa subclass 600 to Australia.   As yet there has been no other correspondence from the immigration department. I am wondering what the problem could be.

Secondly does Australia actually approve Visitor visas for study purpose?

I have tried to contact the immigration services in Nairobi and they complain of work load. Recently they said they will fast track my application so that I get feedback soon, but yet I have not still had any feedback.

I am really feeling disappointed after paying close to 16000 worth of fees.

What can I do?

Comment: Start by checking online if your visa is approved already, since you will usually *not* be notified when it's granted!

Comment: "I have tried to contact the immigration services in Nairobi and they complain of work load. Recently they said they will fast track my application" is that a third-party service provider?

Comment: User has not returned to clarify questions in comments. Putting on hold for now.